# Rail's devise signals a route error when form_tag is used

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

Got this strange issue I don't even know how to label it.

I'm getting this error

No route matches {:controller=>"devise/lite_sport_registration", :action=>"init_by_token"}

when I try to login with either a user or organizer account (those are the two models that devise uses) by entering "/users/sign_in"

When I put this form in the application layout.

```
            <div id="registration" class="registration" style="text-align: center">
            <%= form_tag(:controller => 'lite_sport_registration', :action => 'init_by_token') do |f| %>
            Inscripciones&nbsp;
            <input type="text" value="" name="token" />
            <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Registro" />
            </br>
            <font style="text-align: center;font-style: italic">Escribe tu clave de registro express</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/images/help.png" width="16px" style="vertical-align: middle" />
            <% end %>
        </div>
```

Yet when I change it for this and hardcode the form without tags the problem disappears.

```
                <form method="POST" action="/registration/lite_sports/init">
            Inscripciones&nbsp;
            <input type="text" value="" name="token" />
            <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Registro" />
            </br>
            <font style="text-align: center;font-style: italic">Escribe tu clave de registro express</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/images/help.png" width="16px" style="vertical-align: middle" />
            </font>
            </form>
```

The lite_sport_registration controller is totally unrelated to devise and somehow the issue arrises.  Any idea why?

Here's my route table

```
              new_organizer_session GET    /organizers/sign_in(.:format)                                                   devise/sessions#new
               organizer_session POST   /organizers/sign_in(.:format)                                                   devise/sessions#create
       destroy_organizer_session DELETE /organizers/sign_out(.:format)                                                  devise/sessions#destroy
              organizer_password POST   /organizers/password(.:format)                                                  devise/passwords#create
          new_organizer_password GET    /organizers/password/new(.:format)                                              devise/passwords#new
         edit_organizer_password GET    /organizers/password/edit(.:format)                                             devise/passwords#edit
                                 PUT    /organizers/password(.:format)                                                  devise/passwords#update
   cancel_organizer_registration GET    /organizers/cancel(.:format)                                                    devise/registrations#cancel
          organizer_registration POST   /organizers(.:format)                                                           devise/registrations#create
      new_organizer_registration GET    /organizers/sign_up(.:format)                                                   devise/registrations#new
     edit_organizer_registration GET    /organizers/edit(.:format)                                                      devise/registrations#edit
                                 PUT    /organizers(.:format)                                                           devise/registrations#update
                                 DELETE /organizers(.:format)                                                           devise/registrations#destroy
                new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                        devise/sessions#new
                    user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                        devise/sessions#create
            destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                       devise/sessions#destroy
                   user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                       devise/passwords#create
               new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                   devise/passwords#new
              edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                  devise/passwords#edit
                                 PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                       devise/passwords#update
        cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                         devise/registrations#cancel
               user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                                                devise/registrations#create
           new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                        devise/registrations#new
          edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/registrations#edit
                                 PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                devise/registrations#update
                                 DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                devise/registrations#destroy


       registration_lite_sports_init POST   /registration/lite_sports/init(.:format)                                        lite_sport_registration#init_by_token
                                 GET    /registration/lite_sports/:event_id/start(.:format)                             lite_sport_registration#start
                                 POST   /registration/lite_sports/:event_id/start(.:format)                             lite_sport_registration#start_do
                                 GET    /registration/lite_sports/:event_id/basedata(.:format)                          lite_sport_registration#base_data
                                 POST   /registration/lite_sports/:event_id/basedata(.:format)                          lite_sport_registration#base_data_do
                                 GET    /registration/lite_sports/:event_id/confirm(.:format)                           lite_sport_registration#confirm
                                 POST   /registration/lite_sports/:event_id/confirm(.:format)                           lite_sport_registration#confirm_do
                                 GET    /registration/lite_sports/:event_id/confirmation(.:format)                      lite_sport_registration#confirmation
                                 GET    /registration/lite_sports/:event_id/pdf_confirmation/:registration_id(.:format) lite_sport_registration#pdf_confirmation
                                 GET    /registration/lite_sports/:event_id/recover(.:format)                           lite_sport_registration#recover
                                 POST   /registration/lite_sports/:event_id/recover(.:format)                           lite_sport_registration#recover
```

registration_lite_sports_categories GET    /registration/lite_sports/categories(.:format)                                  lite_sport_registration#categories
                                     GET    /registration/lite_sports/:event_id/terms(.:format)                             lite_sport_registration#terms
     registration_lite_sports_qrcode GET    /registration/lite_sports/qrcode(.:format)                                      lite_sport_registration#qrcode
    registration_lite_sports_barcode GET    /registration/lite_sports/barcode(.:format)                                     lite_sport_registration#barcode

Comment: Is this form nested below the registration form?  If so, it's probably namespaced to the devise routes.

Comment: The form is in the application.html.erb file. The issue arises when I try to login with user or organizer regardless. Those are the two models that devise uses. When the form_tag is placed neither login works, when it's removed both work.
I should add that session is still kept. If I log in as organizer then put the form tag in the previously kept session still works. Logout also works. Only login fails when said tag is in place.

Answer (score 0):

You have a named route here, so just use `registration_lite_sports_init_path` instead of `:controller => 'lite_sport_registration', :action => 'init_by_token'`

Comment: I'll try that. As an added note the usage of the word "init" in /registration/lite_sports/init was also causing devise to reset the user session and log him out. I have changed the url to be action="/registration/lite_sports/quick_start" and the issue with the user being logged out dissappeared.